# Kind of QPainter WYSIWYG Editor?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator, qpainter

I need to draw a complicated object with Qt primitives using QPainter. The thing is I really need to do this in a such uncomfortable way, because it's part of the task. So, is there a kind of WYSIWYG editor, when you just draw object like you would in Gimp or Paint, and get pre-made code for Qt? The object is pretty complicated to draw manually, but I need to get raw code somehow! And yes, I'm totally new to Qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in the [QSvgRenderer](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qsvgrenderer.html#details).

This should allow you to basically draw your object in any program which can export to SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) (e.g. [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/)) and start from there.

Comment: Wow, yes, seems to be what I'm looking for! I'll try and, if it is, will accept the answer.

Comment: Well, it's not really what I need. I need to get the code of the image, not only the same result after compiling it. The reason (stupid, I know) I have to show the code to my tutor that i've made it manually.

Comment: Okay, will think about this more and work out another solution. I think this question (how to make something in a stupid way to meet stupid task requirements) wasn't for stackoverflow, sorry for that, but in case somebody know the answer I'll keep it open for a few days.